# How to pass the result of a promise to a controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

In a controller, I need to retrieve the status of a segment. The segments are loaded from an API using `$resource`.

In the resource, `segmentsresource.js` I have:

```
angular.module('appApp')
  .factory('SegmentsResource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/segments/:id');
  });
```

In the service, `segmentsservice.js` I have:

```
angular.module('appApp')
  .service('SegmentsService', function (SegmentsResource) {
    this.getSegmentStatus = function(segmentId) {
      return SegmentsResource.get({
        id: segmentId
      }, function(segment) {
        return segment.status;
      })
    };
  });
```

I'm trying to do `return segment.status` so I can use the result ('available', 'translated', etc) in the controller, `main.js`:

```
$scope.checkAndEditSegment = function(segmentId) {
  SegmentsService.getSegmentStatus(segmentId)
    .then(function(status) {
      if (status === 'available') {
        console.log('segment is available');
      }
    });
};
```

However, this doesn't work. Console spits: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined'`, so I have a problem with promises.

How to fix this?

Comment: Could you provide the output of `console.log(SegmentsService.getSegmentStatus(segmentId))` in `$scope.checkAndEditSegment` method? Note that the promise is available through `$promise`, see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: In `SegmentsService` return `SegmentsResource.get(....).$promise`, or in `SegmentsService.getSegmentStatus(segmentId)` use `SegmentsService.getSegmentStatus(segmentId).$promise`, because now you are just returning a object.

Answer (score 1):

But why you are taking this long route when you can simply call the factory from controller.

```
angular.module('appApp')
  .factory('SegmentsResource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/segments/:id');
  });

$scope.checkAndEditSegment = function(segmentId) {
  SegmentsResource.get(segmentId)
    .then(function(status) {
      if (status === 'available') {
        console.log('segment is available');
      }
    });
};
```

Comment: because I want to use `getSegmentStatus` in different controllers, that's why it's inside a service.

Comment: but you can always use SegmentsResource in different controllers

Answer (score 0):

I resolved using `$q`:

In the service:

```
this.getSegmentStatus = function(segmentId) {
  var dfd = $q.defer();

  SegmentsResource.get({ id: segmentId }, function(segment) {
    dfd.resolve(segment.status);
  })

  return dfd.promise;
};
```

In the controller:

```
SegmentsService.getSegmentStatus(segmentId)
    .then(function(status) {
      console.log(status);
    });
```